# Unable to get ID of selected item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I am using the code below to get the selected text from the textbox with is using an autocomplete extender. How can I retrieve the Items ID from the database? Is there a way to add something to the code below that will grab the item ID? Thank you

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getSelected(source, eventArgs) {

        document.getElementById('<%=DetailsTextBox.ClientID %>').value = eventArgs.get_value();
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="486px" 
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
    DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" 
            ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" UseContextKey="true" ContextKey="StateDropDown"
            CompletionListElementID="autocompleteDropDownPanel" 
            onclientitemselected="getSelected()">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: What event in the `AutoCompleteExtender` invokes `getSelected`?

Comment: I added the additional code, it is the "onclientitemselected"

Comment: So `eventArgs.get_value();` returns the text selected item by the user and not the ID of the selected item?

Comment: Correct, it returns just all the text selected. I need to somehow just get the ID. I am really struggling with this past 2 days

Comment: Did you try removing parenthesis in OnClientItemSelected? Try Changing onclientitemselected="getSelected" and see if that works.

Comment: Still has the same behavior and returns the text selected not the ID

Comment: Here is a series of blog entries that pertain to AutoCompleteExtender that show grabbing the text and ID of the selected item: [AutoCompleteExtender Series](http://vincexu.blogspot.com/search/label/AutoComplete)

Comment: Could there be a way to get the selected ID from my webmethod then pass it in a session?

Comment: @user1342164 - `Session` is not available client-side and the extender is happening client-side.

Comment: Could there be something wrong with my webservice that the ID is not being returned when I call eventArgs.get_value()?